# Update Table A with content from Table B

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

Im trying to make a trigger in mySQL that will update a colum with data from another table, when i do a insert.

I got table: rtsEP_groups
With: id, name

and table: rtsEP_users
with: id, groups (and alot of others)

And i want to update "groups" in rtsEP_users, with the "id" from rtsEP_groups where "name" is "Student", when there is a new insert in rtsEP_users.

I was working on this trigger, but not sure if its right, and how to finish it.
How to update the right colum.

```
CREATE TRIGGER defaultGroup
AFTER INSERT ON rtsEP_users
BEGIN
DECLARE _group_id INTEGER;
SELECT id INTO _group_id FROM rtsEP_groups WHERE name = "Student"
UPDATE rtsEP_users SET groups = _group_id WHERE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BEFORE INSERT` instead of `AFTER`, so `New` is represent of inserted row that you can update.
Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER defaultGroup BEFORE INSERT ON rtsEP_users
FOR EACH ROW
SET New.groups = (SELECT id FROM rtsEP_groups WHERE name = "Student");
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: @ChristianBekker it may be because [variable name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). Try `@group_id`

Comment: Same result :/ seems strange it wont declare the var

Comment: i think ill just email the host, maybe they have disabled triggers for some reason..

Comment: @ChristianBekker I tried on fiddle that give the same error. But The second `CREATE TRIGGER` i posted, may work. Because it gave me command denied to create trigger

Comment: @ChristianBekker I don't know why the 1st trigger didn't work. I'll delete it